Transform X Year(s), Y Month(s), Z Day(s) into numeric in R
Looking to see if there is a decently easy way to turn a character data point similar to 8 year(s), 6 month(s) and 5 day(s) into a number value like 8.52 (or whatever the calculation is). I am trying to obtain the start date so the transformation is not needed, however, wanting a backup in case I cannot obtain it.
Ideally, want to have the result be something like 8.52 which reflects 8 eights, 6 months and some days. At a loss how to do this.
The data appears like the below
7 year(s), 9 month(s), 9 day(s)
0 year(s), 8 month(s), 9 day(s)
7 year(s), 9 month(s), 4 day(s)
0 year(s), 8 month(s), 9 day(s)
7 year(s), 8 month(s), 29 day(s)
0 year(s), 4 month(s), 9 day(s)

Can you please dput(data) your character data point. Do you have a data frame with 3 character variables or one string, e.g. "8 6 5"?

The lubridate package will be your friend. As will the idea of Julian dates. Have you thought about how you will handle leap years?

library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df |>
  mutate(years = time_length(period(age), unit = "year"))
# # A tibble: 3 × 2
#   age                             years
#   <chr>                           <dbl>
# 1 8 year(s), 6 month(s) 5 day(s) 8.51  
# 2 1 year(s), 0 month(s) 1 day(s) 1.00  
# 3 0 year(s), 1 month(s) 5 day(s) 0.0970

From lubridate the function period() can parse your strings into a period object:
period("8 year(s), 6 month(s) 5 day(s)")
# [1] "8y 6m 5d 0H 0M 0S"

Data
df <- tibble(age = c("8 year(s), 6 month(s) 5 day(s)", "1 year(s), 0 month(s) 1 day(s)", 
                     "0 year(s), 1 month(s) 5 day(s)"))


You could replace away non-numeric characters using gsub, strsplit, create a numeric matrix and do whatsoever calculations on it, e.g.
> f <- \(x) {
+   m <- gsub('\\D+', ' ', x) |> trimws() |> strsplit(' ') |> 
+     do.call(what='rbind') |> type.convert(as.is=TRUE)
+   rowSums(t(t(m)*c(1, 1/12, 1/365.25)))
+ }
> f(x)
[1] 8.51368925 1.00273785 0.09702259


Data:
> dput(x)
c("8 year(s), 6 month(s) and 5 day(s)", "1 year(s), 0 month(s) and 1 day(s)", 
"0 year(s), 1 month(s) and 5 day(s)")


Assuming there's just a string. Only use the mutate part if you already have a data frame with the separated parts.
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)

as_tibble(dat) %>% 
  mutate(value = str_extract_all(dat, "\\d+")) %>% 
  unnest_wider(value, names_sep="", transform=as.numeric) %>% 
  mutate(Year = as.numeric(years(value1) + months(value2) + days(value3), 
                  units = "year"))
# A tibble: 7 × 4
  value1 value2 value3  Year
   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1      8      6      5 8.51 
2      7      9      9 7.77 
3      0      8      9 0.691
4      7      9      4 7.76 
5      0      8      9 0.691
6      7      8     29 7.75 
7      0      4      9 0.358

Data
dat <- c("8 year(s), 6 month(s), 5 day(s)", "7 year(s), 9 month(s), 9 day(s)", 
"0 year(s), 8 month(s), 9 day(s)", "7 year(s), 9 month(s), 4 day(s)", 
"0 year(s), 8 month(s), 9 day(s)", "7 year(s), 8 month(s), 29 day(s)", 
"0 year(s), 4 month(s), 9 day(s)")

